# 画像に値を振りあて、その値を取得したい。

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

今回行いたい作業が、画像自体に値を持たせ`(data-id=1等)`、その画像をクリックすればその値を取得し、その他の`input`欄も埋めた後に送信ボタンを押しデータを送信するという動きを再現したいです。

`<input type='image'>`だとクリックと同時に送信が行われるため、希望の動きが出せないので、
JavaScriptでクリックすればカスタムデータを取得するとしたいのですが、この場合取得したデータを他の`input`欄のデータと一緒に送信するにはどのような記述が必要でしょうか。

現在php laravelで実装を行なっている初学者です。
至らない点が多いとは思いますがご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: チェックボックスやラジオボタンに値を持たせて、その近くにラベルとして画像を表示、ではダメなのでしょうか？ `input type="image"` は submit の代わりとなる送信ボタンになりそうです。

Comment: cubick ラベルで一括りにし、画像自体もボタン化する処理であっているでしょうか？
この際、ラジオボタンのみdisplay:none;で非表示にしても画像はボタンとしても機能することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 画像は1枚だけでしょうか、複数枚でしょうか? 複数枚の場合はラジオボタンのように排他的な選択が必要でしょうか? 画像がまったくクリックされずにフォームが送信された場合はどうしますか?